# PSIM : I'm trying to make a current zero crossing detector

Tags: circuit-design

So I'm trying to make a current zero crossing detector but i want a short impulsion every time the current cross 0 so the switch is up for a very little time.
As I started PSIM not long ago, i'm not sure if the bidirectional switch is the one to use there and I'm missing something such as an edge detector (in the part circled in red).
Could anyone help me please ?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your schematic and add component designators U1, D1, D2, ... R1, C1, V1, V2, etc., so that we can discuss the circuit sensibly. What is the thing to the right of 'A' with a big dot in it? (Do you see why we need the component designators?) It is not clear why you have shown the whole circuit if the question is just about zero-cross which seems to only involve the thing with the dot, the thing that looks like an op-amp and the thing with a '0' in it - which should probably be a ground symbol or '0 V'. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor The thing with a dot is a somewhat uncommon symbol for a current transducer, but I've seen it a few times.

Comment: @Transistor You're right I shouldn't have put all the circuit it was useless. I'm just tryng to control a switch which would be close for a short time everytime the current cross 0.

Comment: The thing with a dot is just to take the actual current and then i compare it to 0, so i get a square signal after the op-amp but i would need something that make a short input everytime the square signal changes.

Comment: resistor + comparator + high pass filter

Comment: oh and a bridge rectifier, to make the bidirectional into always positive pulses etc

Comment: @PeteW Thanks, it worked ! The only issue is that i can't manually regulate the time of the inpulsion

Comment: Great! Converting the positive edge to a fixed-width pulse should be a pretty standard task, maybe search for that specifically?